# How do I add the messaging menu to the xfce-panel?

Tags: xfce, messaging-menu, system-tray, xfce-panel

I am running a pretty peculiar setup right now with LXDE, plank and the XFCE4-panel. This works fine, but I can't seem to find the messaging menu under the system tray options:

[image]

Is there any service I have to add to my autostart apps for the messaging menu to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-indicator-plugin
```

and make sure that you install

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-messages
```

to get the messaging menu. (**Indicator-messages** will put up the Messaging menu on the panel)

Hope this helps.

Comment: `xfce4-indicator-plugin` - That was it, thank you (already had the other ones installed through Unity)

Comment: @Glutanimate Glad that it helped you :)

Comment: I have all those packages installed but the "envelope" doesn't show. How to solve?