# How do I add the messaging menu to the xfce-panel 4.10?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, messaging-menu, xfce-panel

The following answer doesn't work for me: [How do I add the messaging menu to the xfce-panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196845/how-do-i-add-the-messaging-menu-to-the-xfce-panel)

In a fresh 12.04 xubuntu installation (xfce 4.8) I can see the icon for messaging-menu, but in my 13.10 (with xfce 4.10) there's no messaging menu nor sound icon in indicator-plugin.

All needed packages are installed.

The messaging menu icon shows correcly in Unity.

**EDIT:**

Output of `o dpkg -l | grep -e "^rc" -e "^iU"`

```
rc  account-plugin-generic-oauth                  0.10bzr13.03.26-0ubuntu1.1                 amd64        GNOME Control Center account plugin for single signon - generic OAuth
rc  activity-log-manager                          0.9.7-0ubuntu4                             amd64        blacklist configuration user interface for Zeitgeist
rc  activity-log-manager-control-center           0.9.7-0ubuntu4                             all          blacklist configuration for Zeitgeist (transitional package)
rc  apache2.2-common                              2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1                          amd64        Apache HTTP Server common files
rc  appmenu-gtk:amd64                             12.10.3daily13.04.03-0ubuntu1              amd64        Export GTK menus over DBus
rc  appmenu-gtk3:amd64                            12.10.3daily13.04.03-0ubuntu1              amd64        Export GTK menus over DBus
rc  assogiate                                     0.2.1-5                                    amd64        editor of the MIME file types database
rc  dconf-tools                                   0.16.1-1                                   all          transitional dummy package
rc  exult                                         1.2-15.2                                   amd64        engine for Ultima VII (BG, FOV, SI, SS)
rc  exult-studio                                  1.2-15.2                                   amd64        tools for editing and viewing exult games
rc  gadmin-bind                                   0.2.5-2                                    amd64        GTK+ configuration tool for bind9
rc  gadmin-openvpn-client                         0.1.2-4                                    amd64        GTK+ configuration tool for openvpn (client)
rc  gadmin-openvpn-server                         0.1.5-3.1                                  amd64        GTK+ configuration tool for openvpn (server)
rc  gadmin-proftpd                                1:0.4.2-1                                  amd64        GTK+ configuration tool for proftpd
rc  gadmin-rsync                                  0.1.7-1                                    amd64        GTK+ configuration tool for rsync
rc  gadmin-samba                                  0.3.2-0ubuntu1                             amd64        GTK+ configuration tool for samba
rc  gnome-orca                                    3.10.1-0ubuntu0.1                          all          Scriptable screen reader
rc  gnome-sudoku                                  1:3.8.1-1                                  all          Sudoku puzzle game for GNOME
rc  gtk-doc-tools                                 1.19-0ubuntu2                              all          GTK+ documentation tools
rc  gwibber                                       3.6.0-0ubuntu2                             amd64        Open source social networking client for GNOME
rc  iproute                                       1:3.10.0-1ubuntu1                          all          transitional dummy package for iproute2
rc  jockey-common                                 0.9.7-0ubuntu15                            all          user interface and desktop integration for driver management
rc  latex-beamer                                  3.24-1                                     all          LaTeX class to produce presentations
rc  latex-xcolor                                  2.11-1.1                                   all          Easy driver-independent TeX class for color
rc  lesstif2:amd64                                1:0.95.2-1.1                               amd64        OSF/Motif 2.1 implementation released under LGPL
rc  lib32asound2                                  1.0.25-4                                   amd64        shared library for ALSA applications (32 bit)
rc  lib32z1                                       1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1                      amd64        compression library - 32 bit runtime
rc  libaio1:amd64                                 0.3.109-3                                  amd64        Linux kernel AIO access library - shared library
rc  libbamf3-1:amd64                              0.4.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1          amd64        Window matching library - shared library
rc  libboost-iostreams1.49.0                      1.49.0-4                                   amd64        Boost.Iostreams Library
rc  libboost-python1.53.0                         1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                       amd64        Boost.Python Library
rc  libbrlapi0.5:amd64                            4.4-8ubuntu4                               amd64        braille display access via BRLTTY - shared library
rc  libcamel-1.2-40                               3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                           amd64        Evolution MIME message handling library
rc  libcolumbus0-0                                0.4.0daily13.04.16~13.04-0ubuntu1          amd64        error tolerant matching engine - shared library
rc  libdconf-dbus-1-0:amd64                       0.16.1-1                                   amd64        simple configuration storage system - D-Bus library
rc  libdns95                                      1:9.9.2.dfsg.P1-2ubuntu2.1                 amd64        DNS Shared Library used by BIND
rc  libdw1:amd64                                  0.157-1ubuntu1                             amd64        library that provides access to the DWARF debug information
rc  libebackend-1.2-5                             3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                           amd64        Utility library for evolution data servers
rc  libedata-book-1.2-15                          3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                           amd64        Backend library for evolution address books
rc  libedata-cal-1.2-18                           3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                           amd64        Backend library for evolution calendars
rc  libedataserverui-3.0-4                        3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                           amd64        GUI utility library for evolution data servers
rc  libev4                                        1:4.11-1                                   amd64        high-performance event loop library modelled after libevent
rc  libfam0                                       2.7.0-17                                   amd64        Client library to control the FAM daemon
rc  libgnome-desktop-3-4                          3.6.3-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Utility library for loading .desktop files - runtime files
rc  libgnome-keyring0:i386                        3.8.0-2                                    i386         GNOME keyring services library
rc  libgnome-vfsmm-2.6-1c2a                       2.26.0-1build1                             amd64        C++ wrappers for GnomeVFS (shared library)
rc  libgtksourceview-3.0-0:amd64                  3.6.3-0ubuntu1                             amd64        shared libraries for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
rc  libgtkspell-3-0                               3.0.0~hg20110814-1build1                   amd64        spell-checking addon for GTK's TextView widget
rc  libgweather-3-1                               3.6.2-0ubuntu1                             amd64        GWeather shared library
rc  libhal-storage1                               0.5.14-8ubuntu1                            amd64        Hardware Abstraction Layer - shared library for storage devices
rc  libhal1                                       0.5.14-8ubuntu1                            amd64        Hardware Abstraction Layer - shared library
rc  libharfbuzz0:amd64                            0.9.13-1                                   amd64        OpenType text shaping engine
rc  libharfbuzz0:i386                             0.9.13-1                                   i386         OpenType text shaping engine
rc  libhd16                                       16.0-2.2                                   amd64        Hardware identification system library
rc  libibus-1.0-0:amd64                           1.4.2-0ubuntu2                             amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - shared library
rc  libibus-1.0-0:i386                            1.4.2-0ubuntu2                             i386         Intelligent Input Bus - shared library
rc  libical0                                      0.48-2                                     amd64        iCalendar library implementation in C (runtime)
rc  libimobiledevice3                             1.1.4-1ubuntu6.2                           amd64        Library for communicating with the iPhone and iPod Touch
rc  libisc92                                      1:9.9.2.dfsg.P1-2ubuntu2.1                 amd64        ISC Shared Library used by BIND
rc  libllvm3.1:i386                               3.1-2ubuntu2                               i386         Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM), runtime library
rc  libllvm3.2:amd64                              1:3.2repack-7ubuntu1                       amd64        Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM), runtime library
rc  libllvm3.2:i386                               1:3.2repack-7ubuntu1                       i386         Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM), runtime library
rc  libmenu-cache2                                0.4.1-0ubuntu1                             amd64        LXDE implementation of the freedesktop Menu specification
rc  libpackagekit-glib2-14:amd64                  0.7.6-3ubuntu1                             amd64        Library for accessing PackageKit using GLib
rc  libphp5-embed                                 5.5.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2                        amd64        HTML-embedded scripting language (Embedded SAPI library)
rc  libpkcs11-helper1:amd64                       1.09-1build1                               amd64        library that simplifies the interaction with PKCS#11
rc  libpoppler28:amd64                            0.20.5-1ubuntu3                            amd64        PDF rendering library
rc  libraw5:amd64                                 0.14.7-0ubuntu1.13.04.2                    amd64        raw image decoder library
rc  librhythmbox-core6                            2.98-0ubuntu5                              amd64        support library for the rhythmbox music player
rc  libsnmp15                                     5.4.3~dfsg-2.7ubuntu1                      amd64        SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) library
rc  libsyncdaemon-1.0-1                           4.2.0-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Ubuntu One synchronization daemon library
rc  libthunar-vfs-1-2                             1.2.0-3build2                              amd64        Legacy VFS abstraction used in Xfce
rc  libtiff4:amd64                                3.9.7-2ubuntu1                             amd64        Tag Image File Format (TIFF) library (old version)
rc  libubuntuoneui-3.0-1                          4.1.2-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Ubuntu One widget library
rc  libunity-core-6.0-5                           7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1systray1  amd64        Core library for the Unity interface.
rc  libv8-3.8.9.20                                3.8.9.20-2                                 amd64        v8 JavaScript engine - runtime library
rc  libva-drm1:amd64                              1.2.1-0ubuntu0~raring                      amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- DRM runtime
rc  libva-wayland1:amd64                          1.2.1-0ubuntu0~raring                      amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- Wayland runtime
rc  libwayland0:amd64                             1.0.5-0ubuntu1                             amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - shared libraries
rc  libwhoopsie-preferences0                      0.9                                        amd64        Ubuntu error tracker submission settings - shared library
rc  libxfcegui4-4                                 4.10.0-2                                   amd64        Basic GUI C functions for Xfce4
rc  libxml++2.6-2                                 2.36.0-2                                   amd64        C++ interface to the GNOME XML library (libxml2)
rc  linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic                  3.5.0-26.42                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-14-generic                  3.8.0-14.24                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-27-generic                  3.8.0-27.40                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-28-generic                  3.8.0-28.41                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic                  3.8.0-29.42                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic                  3.8.0-30.44                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-31-generic                  3.8.0-31.46                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-32-generic                  3.8.0-32.47                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic            3.5.0-26.42                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-14-generic            3.8.0-14.24                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-27-generic            3.8.0-27.40                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-28-generic            3.8.0-28.41                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic            3.8.0-29.42                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-30-generic            3.8.0-30.44                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-31-generic            3.8.0-31.46                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-32-generic            3.8.0-32.47                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  lxmenu-data                                   0.1.2-2                                    all          LXDE freedesktop.org menu specification
rc  mail-notification                             5.4.dfsg.1-8                               amd64        mail notification in system tray
rc  nvidia-310                                    319.49-0ubuntu1~raring~xup1                amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-310
rc  nvidia-319                                    319.49-0ubuntu1~raring~xup1                amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
rc  nvidia-settings-319                           319.49-0ubuntu1~raring~xup1                amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
rc  openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64                  6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu2                       amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
rc  openvpn                                       2.2.1-8ubuntu3                             amd64        virtual private network daemon
rc  pdfjam                                        2013.20130722-1                            all          TeX Live: transitional dummy package
rc  pgf                                           2.10-1                                     all          TeX Portable Graphic Format
rc  php5-cli                                      5.5.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2                        amd64        command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
rc  php5-readline                                 5.5.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2                        amd64        Readline module for php5
rc  proftpd-basic                                 1.3.4a-4+nmu1                              amd64        Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - binaries
rc  prosper                                       1.00.4+cvs.2007.05.01-4                    all          LaTeX class for writing transparencies
rc  squeeze                                       0.2.3-12build1                             amd64        modern and advanced archive manager for Xfce
rc  teamviewer                                    8.0.17147                                  amd64        TeamViewer (Remote Control Application)
rc  texlive-doc-base                              2012.20120611-1                            all          TeX Live: TeX Live documentation
rc  texlive-extra-utils                           2013.20130722-1                            all          TeX Live: TeX auxiliary programs
rc  texlive-font-utils                            2013.20130722-1                            all          TeX Live: Graphics and font utilities
rc  texlive-generic-recommended                   2013.20130722-1                            all          TeX Live: Generic recommended packages
rc  texlive-latex-base                            2013.20130722-1                            all          TeX Live: LaTeX fundamental packages
rc  texlive-latex-base-doc                        2013.20130722-1                            all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-base
rc  texlive-latex-recommended                     2013.20130722-1                            all          TeX Live: LaTeX recommended packages
rc  texlive-latex-recommended-doc                 2013.20130722-1                            all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-recommended
rc  texlive-pstricks                              2013.20130722-1                            all          TeX Live: PSTricks
rc  texlive-pstricks-doc                          2013.20130722-1                            all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-pstricks
rc  timidity                                      2.13.2-40.1                                amd64        Software sound renderer (MIDI sequencer, MOD player)
rc  timidity-daemon                               2.13.2-40.1                                all          runs TiMidity++ as a system-wide MIDI sequencer
rc  unity-common                                  7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1systray1  all          Common files for the Unity interface.
rc  whoopsie-preferences                          0.9                                        amd64        System preferences for error reporting
rc  wine-mpg2splt-installer                       0.8.6~ubuntu13.10.1                        all          wine-mpg2splt-installer provides a convient tool that downloads and installs all of the components necessary to run mpg2splt.ax under Wine.
rc  wine-silverlight5.1-installer                 0.8.6~ubuntu13.10.1                        all          wine-silverlight5.1-installer provides a convient tool that downloads and installs all of the components necessary to run Silverlight 5.1 under Wine.
rc  xfce-keyboard-shortcuts                       4.11.0-0ubuntu1~ppa0.13.10.1               all          xfce keyboard shortcuts configuration (transitional package)
rc  xfce4-notes                                   1.7.7-3ubuntu2                             amd64        Notes application for the Xfce4 desktop
rc  xul-ext-calendar-timezones                    1:24.0+build1-0ubuntu1                     amd64        Calendar Extension for Thunderbird (transitional package)
rc  zeitgeist-core                                0.9.14-0ubuntu3                            amd64        event logging framework - engine
rc  zeitgeist-datahub                             0.9.14-0ubuntu3                            amd64        event logging framework - passive logging daemon
```

Output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep indicator`

```
ii  banshee-extension-appindicator                2.4.0-2ubuntu1                             all          Application Indicator extension for Banshee
ii  calendar-indicator                            0.2.0-0extras13.10.1                       all          An indicator for Google Calendar
ii  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1                      12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu2            amd64        Typelib files for libappindicator3-1.
ii  gir1.2-syncmenu-0.1                           12.10.5+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1            amd64        indicator for synchronisation processes status - bindings
ii  indicator-applet                              12.10.2+13.10.20130924.2-0ubuntu1          amd64        GNOME panel indicator applet
ii  indicator-applet-complete                     12.10.2+13.10.20130924.2-0ubuntu1          amd64        Clone of the GNOME panel indicator applet
ii  indicator-applet-session                      12.10.2+13.10.20130924.2-0ubuntu1          amd64        Clone of the GNOME panel indicator applet
ii  indicator-application                         12.10.1daily13.01.25-0ubuntu1              amd64        Application Indicators
ii  indicator-application-gtk2                    12.10.0.1-0ubuntu2                         amd64        Application Indicators
ii  indicator-appmenu                             13.01.0+13.10.20130930-0ubuntu1            amd64        Indicator for application menus.
ii  indicator-bluetooth                           0.0.6+13.10.20131016-0ubuntu1              amd64        System bluetooth indicator.
ii  indicator-datetime                            13.10.0+13.10.20131023.2-0ubuntu1          amd64        Simple clock
ii  indicator-keyboard                            0.0.0+13.10.20131010.1-0ubuntu1            amd64        Keyboard indicator
ii  indicator-messages                            13.10.1+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1            amd64        indicator that collects messages that need a response
ii  indicator-power                               12.10.6+13.10.20131008-0ubuntu1            amd64        Indicator showing power state.
ii  indicator-printers                            0.1.7daily13.03.01-0ubuntu1                amd64        indicator showing active print jobs
ii  indicator-session                             12.10.5+13.10.20131023.1-0ubuntu1          amd64        indicator showing session management, status and user switching
ii  indicator-sound                               12.10.2+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1            amd64        System sound indicator.
ii  indicator-sound-gtk2                          12.10.0.1-0ubuntu2                         amd64        System sound indicator.
ii  indicator-sync                                12.10.5+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1            amd64        indicator for synchronisation processes status
ii  indicator-weather                             13.7.1                                     all          indicator that displays weather information
ii  libappindicator0.1-cil                        12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu2            all          CLI bindings for libappindicator
ii  libappindicator1                              12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu2            amd64        Application Indicators
ii  libappindicator3-1                            12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu2            amd64        Application Indicators
ii  libindicate-gtk3                              12.10.1-0ubuntu3                           amd64        library for raising indicators via DBus - GTK+ bindings
ii  libindicate5                                  12.10.1-0ubuntu3                           amd64        library for raising indicators via DBus
ii  libindicator-dev                              12.10.2+13.10.20130913-0ubuntu2            amd64        panel indicator applet - library development files
ii  libindicator3-7                               12.10.2+13.10.20130913-0ubuntu2            amd64        panel indicator applet - shared library
ii  libindicator3-dev                             12.10.2+13.10.20130913-0ubuntu2            amd64        panel indicator applet - library development files
ii  libindicator7                                 12.10.2+13.10.20130913-0ubuntu2            amd64        panel indicator applet - shared library
ii  libsync-menu1:amd64                           12.10.5+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1            amd64        indicator for synchronisation processes status - libraries
ii  python-appindicator                           12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu2            amd64        Python bindings for libappindicator
ii  sni-qt:amd64                                  0.2.6-0ubuntu1                             amd64        indicator support for Qt
ii  sni-qt:i386                                   0.2.6-0ubuntu1                             i386         indicator support for Qt
ii  telepathy-indicator                           0.3.1daily13.06.19-0ubuntu1                amd64        Desktop service to integrate Telepathy with the messaging menu.
ii  touchpad-indicator                            0.9.5-0extras13.04.1                       all          An indicator for the touchpad
ii  xchat-gnome-indicator                         0.3.11-0ubuntu4                            amd64        XChat-GNOME Indicator Plugin
ii  xchat-indicator                               0.3.11-0ubuntu4                            amd64        XChat Indicator Plugin
ii  xfce4-indicator-plugin                        0.5.0-2ubuntu2                             amd64        plugin to display information from applications in the Xfce4 panel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sound indicator is a bug - referenced in the release notes.

[No sound settings available in the settings manager window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360806/volume-indicator-issue-after-xubuntu-13-10-upgrade/360840#360840)

The messaging menu is caused (afaik) by the same underlying issue.

If you want to try the gtk3 indicators in a gtk2 panel - the instructions can be found here. I've been using that setup for a while.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Xubuntu/Roadmap/Specifications/Saucy/Gtk3Indicators

[image]

Comment: after those steps, indicator-plugin works as he should, but it crashes immediately... now I can't revert to original...

Comment: Have you tried logging out/in? I hope you read the Usage notes and backed up the existing. " The first time you run it you might get crashes because gtk2 indicator backends are still running."

Comment: tried, obvously

Comment: Edit your question and post the output of these commands: `sudo dpkg -l  grep -e "^rc" -e "^iU"` and `sudo dpkg -l | grep indicator`

Comment: please provide how to revert to previous state!!!

Comment: @jasmines: I was wondering how did you got this output :D After watching carefully I noticed that I missed the **`|`** in one of the command above. So the command will be: `sudo dpkg -l | grep -e "^rc" -e "^iU"`

Comment: @jasmines: I don't know whether you problem is solve or not but from the output it seems that you've a lot of residual packages. This command will help to remove them all: `sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l | grep "^rc" | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')`